# Hijacking a client socket

Tags: python, sockets, networking, server, scapy

I have set up a server socket (plain raw socket) listening on `port A`. A client now connects to this server. OS opens up a port for the client for this purpose. Say `port B` is allocated to this client. Now my question is, can a 3<sup>rd</sup> script connect to this `port B` and send data. Or in other words can I spoof a response to the client as if it was coming from the server? I tried spoofing it using scapy, but it wasnt working.

**server.py**

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(("localhost", A))
s.listen(10)
ns, cli_addr = s.accept()
time.sleep(30) # so that i can trigger my 3rd script
```

**goodclient.py**

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(("localhost", A))
print s.getsockname() # to get the local port of client - B
s.recv(1024)
```

**badboy.py**

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(("localhost", B)) # connection refused error
s.send("hihihi")
```

**scapybadboy.py**

```
pack = IP(src="localhost", dst="localhost") / TCP(sport=A, dport=B) / "Hello"
send(pack) # Packet sent but not received by the client
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because server and client using `SOCK_STREAM` sockets, they both aware of TCP session(including port, IP and (**SEQ_NUMBER**,**ACK_NUMBER**)), so when session is already in process, you will have to perform [TCP hikacking](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/tcp-hijacking/) and [IP spoofing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address_spoofing) in order to send messages in stream.

In other words, you will have to guess(or steal) ACK number of server in order to send fake messages to client using `badclient`.

However, if you will make somehow `goodclient` answer you and not a server you should run the following:

`iptables -A FORWARD -j NFQUEUE --queue-num 1` , because your operating system doesn't  know about session that you just "opened" with goodclient and it will send RST packet. This command will prevent it.

Comment: so the only thing i need to add is the ack number?